# Wanting to update with two conditions both with multiple values

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a status system that shows satus of units, if you press a button the status of the task will update if your name is like one of the roles for that task. however i don't want the status to downgrade, it needs to display the latest status. So what i wanted to do is like this

update status Set status=cleared where jobtask1=name or jobtask2=name AND status=in_progress OR status=in_wait

```
UPDATE data 
SET status='cleared' WHERE person1='$name' OR person2='$name' OR person3='$name' OR person4='$name' 
AND status='in_progress' OR status='preparation' OR status='in_wait' OR 
status=''
```

So it results in checking if one of the persons is the person updating the status or if the status is like one of the specified statusses. I want it to check if the person is like the person updating the status, if so then check if the status is like one of the specified statusses and if both are correct update the status.

Comment: Add parenthesis.

Comment: This db design seems to be a bit messy - think about [normalization](https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php). persons and tasks should be rows instead of columns. What if there are 100 or more persons or tasks?

Comment: You just need to add parenthesis as @Salman says **WHERE (person1='$name' OR person2='$name' OR person3='$name' OR person4='$name') 
AND (status='in_progress' OR status='preparation' OR status='in_wait' OR 
status='')**. And as B001, think about changing your DB structure and normalize it

Comment: @nacho, thanks that worked,allso each task only takes max 4 persons, now it is easyer for me to access one of the roles for each task,allso could you maybe make your comment an awnser so i can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try to use SWITCH CASE logic

```
UPDATE data 
SET status = 
     CASE 
         WHEN (person1='$name' OR person2='$name' OR person3='$name' OR person4='$name') THEN 'cleared' 
         WHEN (<second_condition>) THEN 'in_progress'
         ...
         ELSE ''
     END
```

You should also consider redesigning the DB according to normalization principles.

Comment: So if i understand, when one of the persons corresponds to the name, it sets it to cleared, and for the second condition i enter the status it needs to be in to be changed. But i need to only update if both conditions are true. How do i do this?

Comment: Then you should use parenthesis as mentioned in the comments  above

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Salman and nacho for the solution, I just needed to add parenthesis.